# Single-value decomposition of a sparse matrix

Tags: matrix, clojure, svd

I have a relatively big matrix of which I would like to compute the single-value decomposition. Using the straight-forward `linear/svd` function of core.matrix (using the `:vectorz` implementation) unfortunately leads to an out-of-memory exception -- my machine has comparingly little memory for a dev machine (8GB, Java heap space is set to max at 5GB).

The matrix has the dimensions `[422, 23069]` and is relatively sparse (~1.74% of the values are non-zero), so my next attempt was converting the matrix to a `sparse-matrix`:

```
(def sparse-fs (matrix/sparse-matrix fs))
```

This surprisingly fails with an `ArrayOutOfBoundsException` in the Java code. I could work around this by creating a sparse matrix first and then setting the non-zero values:

```
user> (def sparse-fs (matrix/sparse-matrix [422 23069]))
#'user/sfs
user> (count
        (map-indexed
          (fn [row line]
           (map-indexed
            (fn [col val]
              (when (not (= val 0.0))
                (matrix/mset! sparse-fs row col val)))))
        fs))
422
```

However, calling `linear/svd` on this sparse matrix also fails, as the protocol for svd is apparently not implemented:

```
user> (def svd-fs (linear/svd sparse-fs))
CompilerException java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No implementation of method: :svd of protocol: 
#'clojure.core.matrix.protocols/PSVDDecomposition found for class: mikera.vectorz.Vector2,
```

I'm currently out of ideas on how to progress from here and would appreciate any input on how I could fit my matrix (and the svd computation) into my relatively small memory.

**Update:**
The protocol problem comes from me still trying to use `clojure.core.matrix/sparse-matrix`, which intended use I apparently don't understand. Instead I can use `new-sparse-array` which generates an instance implementing `AMatrix`, for which the decomposition protocol is implemented:

```
user> (def foo-sparse (matrix/sparse-matrix [422 23069]))
#'user/foo-sparse
user> (type foo-sparse)
mikera.vectorz.Vector2
user> (matrix/dimensionality foo-sparse)
1
user> (def foo-sparse (matrix/new-sparse-array [422 23069]))
#'user/foo-sparse
user> (matrix/dimensionality foo-sparse)
2
user> (type foo-sparse)
mikera.matrixx.impl.SparseRowMatrix
```

Unfortunately, when I call `linear/svd` on this matrix, I'm back at my out of memory error:

```
1. Caused by java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
   Java heap space

         DoubleArrays.java:  724  mikera.vectorz.util.DoubleArrays/createStorage
               Matrix.java:   45  mikera.matrixx.Matrix/<init>
               Matrix.java:   56  mikera.matrixx.Matrix/create
               Matrix.java:  653  mikera.matrixx.Matrix/createIdentity
        BidiagonalRow.java:  174  mikera.matrixx.decompose.impl.bidiagonal.BidiagonalRow/handleU
        BidiagonalRow.java:  155  mikera.matrixx.decompose.impl.bidiagonal.BidiagonalRow/getU
        BidiagonalRow.java:  115  mikera.matrixx.decompose.impl.bidiagonal.BidiagonalRow/_decompose
        BidiagonalRow.java:   78  mikera.matrixx.decompose.impl.bidiagonal.BidiagonalRow/decompose
           Bidiagonal.java:   21  mikera.matrixx.decompose.Bidiagonal/decompose
        SvdImplicitQr.java:  177  mikera.matrixx.decompose.impl.svd.SvdImplicitQr/bidiagonalization
        SvdImplicitQr.java:  154  mikera.matrixx.decompose.impl.svd.SvdImplicitQr/_decompose
        SvdImplicitQr.java:   89  mikera.matrixx.decompose.impl.svd.SvdImplicitQr/decompose
                  SVD.java:   31  mikera.matrixx.decompose.SVD/decompose
            matrix_api.clj:  334  mikera.vectorz.matrix-api/eval26238/fn
            protocols.cljc: 1150  clojure.core.matrix.protocols$eval21076$fn__21077$G__21067__21084/invoke
               linear.cljc:  105  clojure.core.matrix.linear$svd/invoke
```

I suspect that this might be related to the vectorz-clj [issue 18 that operations on sparse matrices don't produce sparse results](https://github.com/mikera/vectorz-clj/issues/18).

Any alternatives?

Comment: Can you try using "Colt" instead? I know it is not quite what you want but they have sparse matrix support and SVD implemented. http://dst.lbl.gov/ACSSoftware/colt/api/cern/colt/matrix/linalg/SingularValueDecomposition.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could work around my memory problem on the `svd` computation by using the `:clatrix` implementation. Clatrix doesn't support sparse matrixes, but seems to use less memory on svd computation.